# Compare two names and initials

Tags: vb.net, string, split

I have got a string variable called 'InvName'

I want to split the value of string and add it to a List (of String)..

```
Dim InvName as string = "Mr John Paul Smith"
Dim InvNameList As List(Of String)
InvNameList.AddRange(InvName.Split({" ", "_", ".", vbTab}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
```

Above is my code but it won't let me add the range

**Error :
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Any idea?

Comment: What language? VB? How does it not let you add the range? Does it throw an error?

Comment: vb.net == Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no VB expert, but I believe you need to initialize the array. Try this instead:

```
Dim InvNameList As New List(Of String)
```